# Is it considered a code smell to not delete static pointers of a singleton?

Tags: c++, code-smell, singleton, raii

I have a singleton that needs to be initialized at the start of the program and it will live on until the end of the program. As is usual in this pattern, a function initializing the singleton creates a static pointer member to itself that is returned from the get() method. My usual C++ instinct tells me that if something is initialized with `new` in a constructor, it should be deleted in a destructor always.

I do feel that my intuition is correct for the simple fact that if I instinctively remember to always delete what I allocate with no exception, I will never forget it when it is actually necessary. But that is a personal coding preference and, I admit, quite a weak argument.

If I were performing code review and had to convince someone that not deleting this allocated memory can lead to potential error later on, how could I argument my case? Or is my intuition wrong and it does actually come down to personal coding preferences?

---

As a concrete example: the singleton I'm writing is a class that wraps OpenGL calls 1:1, so the client code can use unoptimized calls that are later optimized inside the singleton class - for example if I need to create 100 buffers, I can create them one by one in client code and if the profiler shows this causes a bottleneck, the singleton can create them in minimal possible calls without changes to client call. I'd appreciate if the answers were possibly general and not fixated on this specific example.

Comment: Just use `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers for the static variable. That way, you get automatic destruction. Raw-pointers are only good for two things: representing nullable references to non-owned data, or as a low level implementation detail for implementing smart pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I need to use a piece of memory throughout the lifespan of my program, is it really necessary to free it right before program termination?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305930/if-i-need-to-use-a-piece-of-memory-throughout-the-lifespan-of-my-program-is-it)

Comment: If it's really a singleton in c++, you should use [Scott Meyers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/how-do-you-implement-the-singleton-design-pattern) implementation, with a local lazy instantiation instead of `new`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I cannot decide if that is really clever or an ugly hack. Static member to the singleton instance clearly indicates to whom that instance belongs and who should manage it. Static variables inside functions/methods feel more ephemeral to me, existing in some corner of the program that I shouldn't concern myself with.

Comment: Static local variables in c++ very well define ownership.

Comment: @DocBrown there is a lot of good information in the linked answers but I would still be against marking this question as duplicate. The linked question talks about deleting memory "in general", which "in general" is always a good idea. With singleton that is extremely unlikely to be moved to non-global scope, the argument is harder to make. An answer like the one from Caleth wouldn't fit under the linked question, as it's just a small detail compared to other possible issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a style rule that permits exceptions, then it can't be enforced mechanically, and humans have to verify that it fits a permitted exception, and will have to continue to verify that as the codebase changes. If instead you permit no exceptions, the style rule can be enforced mechanically, and no-one has to verify exceptional cases.

Answer (score 2):

The rule for singletons is: They are created automatically the first time they are needed, and they live as long as the program is running. You never call a constructor. You never call a destructor. In C++ a singleton cannot be a static class instance because the runtime will try to destruct them. Especially in a multithreaded environment some thread might be using the singleton.